# how to get current EST time in angular considering with date light saving

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am new to angular. I need to get the current EST time with considering daylight saving.I gone through getTimeOffset. But I couldn't get it with daylight approach and with 24 hours format.

In case 05:00 PM EST, I need value as 16:00. Please help me on this

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use below code to get EST time in angular

```
let dd = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform(new Date(), 'HH' , 'EDT');

if(parseInt(dd) >= 17){
console.log("Time is greater than 05:00 PM EST");
}else{
console.log("Time is less than 05:00 PM EST");
}
```